# Send e-mail to multiple e-mail addresses from report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with customer information, including e-mail addresses. I can make sure Outlook is opened upon clicking an e-mail address:

```vb
="MailTo:" & Fields!Email.Value)
```

However, now I want to have a link in the report header which opens Outlook with *all* e-mail addresses in the report. I can create a stored procerdure like this:

```sql
DECLARE @_Email varchar(MAX)

SELECT @_Email = COALESCE(@_Email + '; ', '') + EmailAddress
FROM   MyTable

SELECT @_Email
```

However, the report has a lot of parameters already, and this is going to be another big procedure. Is there any easier way to do it using vbscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

1. Create a dataset "EmailAddresses" with a query like `SELECT EmailAddress FROM MyTable`
2. [Create a *MultiValue* Text parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx) `@EmailAddresses`
3. Set the default value to be retrieved from the "EmailAddresses" dataset
4. Update your expression to `="Mailto:" & Join(Parameters!EmailAddresses.Value, "; ")`

Per your choice you can keep the parameter visible, or make it internal/hidden.